# SalesTermQuery unauthorized when querying with a %

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to query for a SalesTerm with the name "1% Net 30". However, it keeps throwing an unauthorized exception.

If I query for the sales term name "Test" with no spaces or percentage signs it works fine. I have tried escaping the % using the Uri object with no success.

The code looks like this:

```
string name = "1% Net 30";
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SalesTermQuery qboQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SalesTermQuery();

qboQuery.Name = name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to XML encode the % sign for it to be passed in the XML request.

regards,
Jarred